# How to reject unexpected JSON data (keys) using Swift Codable framework

Tags: swift, codable

I'm curious, is there a way to reject arbitrary data from being ignored by JSONDecoder in Swift? Even implementing `init(decoder:)` manually, I can't see a way of catching the unexpected keys. I have tried, but can't find an answer out there. Could someone point me in the right direction, please? Eg is there a decoding strategy flag I can set somewhere that will help with this?

Here's some code to show the problem (expecting fatal error if `importData` called):

```swift
private struct DataRecord {
    var greeting: String = "Hello"
}

// Adding Codable in an extension allows us to keep the compiler generated init().
extension DataRecord: Codable {
    enum CodingKeys: CodingKey, CaseIterable {
        case greeting
    }

    func encode(to encoder: Encoder) throws {
        var container = encoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)

        try container.encode(greeting, forKey: .greeting)
    }
        
    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        greeting = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .greeting)
        
        // An attempt at rejecting unrecognised keys, but allKeys doesn't include "unexpected_key"
        let foundKeys = Set(container.allKeys.map { $0.stringValue })
        let validKeys = Set(CodingKeys.allCases.map { $0.stringValue })
        let invalidKeys = foundKeys.subtracting(validKeys)
        
        print("found: \(foundKeys)")
        print("valid: \(validKeys)")
        print("invalid: \(invalidKeys)")
        
        guard invalidKeys.isEmpty else {
            fatalError("Bad Keys Found: \(invalidKeys)")
        }
    }
}

func importData() {
    let stringData = """
{
    "greeting": "Hello World!",
    "unexpected_key": "This should fail!"
}
"""
    let data = stringData.data(using:.utf8)!
    let decoder = JSONDecoder()
    
    let record = try! decoder.decode(DataRecord.self, from: data) // <-- this should fail
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It appears that when using `allKeys`, the initialiser of the coding key type is used to create the coding key instances. However, if the initialiser fails (returns nil), then that key is not included in the `allKeys` array.

So one way to do this is to just create a key type that has an initialiser that never fails:

```
struct AnyCodingKey: CodingKey {
    var stringValue: String
    
    init?(stringValue: String) {
        self.stringValue = stringValue
    }
    
    var intValue: Int?
    
    init?(intValue: Int) {
        self.intValue = intValue
        self.stringValue = "\(intValue)"
    }
}
```

Then, get the container with `AnyCodingKey`, and compare with all the cases of your struct's enum coding key.

```
init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
    let allKeysContainer = try decoder.container(keyedBy: AnyCodingKey.self)
    if Set(CodingKeys.allCases.map(\.stringValue)) != Set(allKeysContainer.allKeys.map(\.stringValue)) {
        // throw some error as you like
        throw MyDecodingError.invalidKey
    }
    
    let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
    greeting = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .greeting)
}
```

The disadvantage of this is of course that you have to implement this explicit decoding for every structs in the hierarchy :(